# Why does :restore_manifest in cap staging deploy fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

Having setup capistrano on my rails app I was deploying okay I then went and changed some css values on my local site. This was fine but then when I went to deploy my site with `cap staging deploy` it started to do its normal routine tasks just fine but when it came to capistrano's precompile task for assets it failed. I have managed to source where it is going wrong on the capistrano area and thats here:

```
task :backup_manifest do
      on roles(fetch(:assets_roles)) do
        within release_path do
          execute :cp,
            release_path.join('public', fetch(:assets_prefix), 'manifest*'),
            release_path.join('assets_manifest_backup')
        end
      end
    end

task :restore_manifest do
          on roles(fetch(:assets_roles)) do
            within release_path do
              source = release_path.join('assets_manifest_backup')
              target = capture(:ls, release_path.join('public', fetch(:assets_prefix),
                                                      'manifest*')).strip
              if test "[[ -f #{source} && -f #{target} ]]"
                execute :cp, source, target
              else
                msg = 'Rails assets manifest file (or backup file) not found.'
                warn msg
                fail Capistrano::FileNotFound, msg
              end
            end
          end
        end
```

It fails here where you have `within release_path do` as thats in the stack trace but I do not know why it does that as i have not changed any tasks at all just ccs tweaks.
Here are my deployment settings for capistrano:

## deploy.rb

```
lock '3.1.0'
server "188.226.182.102"

set :application, "ForgeAndCo"
set :scm, "git"
set :repo_url, "git@made-by-mark.beanstalkapp.com:/made-by-mark/forge.git"
# set :scm_passphrase, ""

set :user, "deploy"
set :use_sudo, false

set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: true,
  port: 14439
}

set :assets_prefix, 'prepackaged-assets'

# files we want symlinking to specific entries in shared.
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

# dirs we want symlinking to shared
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake]  = "bundle exec rake" #8
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rails] = "bundle exec rails"

set :branch, ENV["REVISION"] || ENV["BRANCH_NAME"] || "master"


set :keep_releases, 20


namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart passenger without service interruption (keep requests in a queue while restarting)'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')

      unless execute :curl, '-s -k --location localhost | grep "Forge" > /dev/null'
        exit 1
      end
    end
  end


end

after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
```

## deploy/staging.rb

```
role :app, %w{deploy@188.226.182.102}
role :web, %w{deploy@188.226.182.102}
role :db,  %w{deploy@188.226.182.102}

# Extended Server Syntax
# ======================
# This can be used to drop a more detailed server
# definition into the server list. The second argument
# something that quacks like a hash can be used to set
# extended properties on the server.
# server 'example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app}, my_property: :my_value

set :stage, :staging

server "188.226.182.102", user: "deploy", roles: %w{web app db}
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/forge_staging"

set :rails_env, 'staging'                  # If the environment differs from the stage name
set :migration_role, 'migrator'            # Defaults to 'db'
set :assets_roles, [:web, :app]            # Defaults to [:web]
set :assets_prefix, 'prepackaged-assets'   # Defaults to 'assets' this should match config.assets.prefix in your rails config/application.rb

set :branch, ENV["REVISION"] || ENV["BRANCH_NAME"] || "master"
```

Does anyone know why it would fail at this task at all?

Comment: Did you run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` locally to check whether your capistrano is doing just fine but the precompile actually does fail?

Comment: so I did `rake assets:precompile` earlier and that worked, in my application.rb I have this: `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` I am not sure if I should switch that to true?

Comment: Tobias Schoknecht: have you ever had this issue?

Comment: Fortunately not. Interesting though that precompile works locally. Well, you can always test whether changing the setting changes anything, but e.g. Heroku requires it to be false so I doubt that that's it

Comment: hmm short of jumping of a cliff I am not sure what to actually do!!

Comment: What exactly does the error message say?

Comment: It says `cp: cannot stat `/home/deploy/forge_staging/releases/20140318095612/public/prepackaged-assets/manifest*': No such file or directory`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49926/discussion-between-m-dunbavan-and-tobias-schoknecht)

Comment: Does the directory /home/deploy/forge_staging/releases/20140318095612/public/prepackaged-assets/ exist?